# how to integrate the duplicated index?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Assume I have a dataframe, ABC, that looks like:

```
                   a     b     c    d    e
    2016-06-01     3     6    NAN   4    8
    2016-06-01     3    NAN    5   NAN  NAN
    2016-06-01    NAN   NAN   NAN   4    8
    2017-03-01     1     7     8   NAN  NAN
    2017-03-01    NAN   NAN    8    9    3
    2017-06-01    NAN    3    NAN  NAN   6 
    2017-06-01     8     3     4    7   NAN
```

the index is datetime, and I want it to look like:

```
                   a     b     c    d    e
    2016-06-01     3     6     5    4    8
    2017-03-01     1     7     8    9    3
    2017-06-01     8     3     4    7    6
```

I tried to code like this:

```
for i in ABC.index.strftime('%Y-%m-%d'):
    for j in ABC:
        if ABC[i][j].isna().any() and ABC[i][j].notna().any()
           ABC[i][j].fillna(ABC[i][j][ABC[i][j].notna()][0],inplace = True)
print(ABC)
```

I thought I could make a dataframe like this:

```
                   a     b     c    d    e
    2016-06-01     3     6     5    4    8
    2016-06-01     3     6     5    4    8
    2016-06-01     3     6     5    4    8
    2017-03-01     1     7     8    9    3
    2017-03-01     1     7     8    9    3
    2017-06-01     8     3     4    7    6 
    2017-06-01     8     3     4    7    6
```

and then I can just use drop_duplicates to achieve my goal, but I failed.
(inplace = True) seems not working, and what I printed out is just the same as the original dataframe.
I don't know what's wrong and have no idea how to fix it.
Could somebody tell me how to fix it or a better way to achieve my goal?
thanks a lot.

Comment: please post a sample dataframe. Is your dataframe really looking like the first example?

Comment: Hi, welcome to StackOverflow. Here's a one-liner that might get you started: `df.groupby("date").fillna(method="ffill").dropna(how="any").drop_duplicates()` Note that this is not guaranteed to work for all conditions, but it does work for your sample df.

Comment: Assuming that the date column is an index, you can reset the index of the `df` so that the dates become a column. Then you can do a `groupby` on the dates and do a `ffill()`. You can set the date column back as an index later

Comment: If your data is sometimes different, you would need a custom aggregator. See: https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/31007/merge-information-of-rows-with-same-date

Answer (score 2):

If you have a data frame of `floats`, simply groupby the index and use `first`, which grabs first non-NA value

```
df.groupby(level=0).first()
```

---

```
              a    b    c    d    e
2016-06-01  3.0  6.0  5.0  4.0  8.0
2017-03-01  1.0  7.0  8.0  9.0  3.0
2017-06-01  8.0  3.0  4.0  7.0  6.0
```

Just notice that `NAN` is not considered `NaN`, so it could be that you columns with `object` dtype there.

To fix, just `pd.to_numeric` or `df.astype(float)` - many SO threads on this.